# How to Integrate IBM Rational Team Concert and Power bi tool

Tags: configuration, powerbi, rational-team-concert

Please help me to Integrate IBM Rational Team Concert and Power bi tool.

Thanks in advance, 
Maduraipandian Manivel.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/) is a business intelligence platform that provides nontechnical business users with tools for aggregating, analyzing, visualizing and sharing data.

I don't know of an official integration between that platform and IBM RTC.

You would need to create, as [mentioned in this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/259625/how-can-i-automate-the-export-of-reports-to-a-csv-or-text-file-for-ingestion-into-power-bi), your own RTC reports or queries and automatically export them to a designated directory.
Then, the csv or text files could be ingested into Microsoft Power BI.